# Kubernetes - Ingress vs Nginx with Loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ingress

AFAIK an Ingress is just an abstraction layer to a LoadBalancer service targeting Nginx (or others)

Are there features only an ingress can provide? Are there any drawbacks of using LoadBalancer + Nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AFAIK an Ingress is just an abstraction layer to a LoadBalancer service targeting Nginx (or others)

That's only partially true; you can use `hostNetworking: true` and expose the Ingress controller directly off of the Nodes if you wish, skipping the SDN and the need for a Load Balancer (although with the *disadvantage* of exposing the ports of your Nodes directly to the Internet) -- and roughly the same idea with `Service` of `type: NodePort` just with extra port silliness

A lot of folks do use an Ingress controller behind a LoadBalancer in order to segregate the Nodes from the Internet, but its not a *requirement*

One should also be aware of the [ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller#readme) which goes the other way: asking the LB to do the `host:` and URI routing before it reaches the cluster, and having no(?) nginx component running in the cluster

> Are there features only an ingress can provide?

**Only**? Unlikely. **Convenient** and cloud-portable? Extremely

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but the reason most folks use a single LB and an in-cluster Ingress controller is the massive cost savings of just paying for one LB with almost limitless Ingress resources. Without an Ingress, one would need to use `Service` of `type: LoadBalaner`, and then wait while kubernetes provisions a fresh LB for each Service, costing time and money

> Are there any drawbacks of using LoadBalancer + Nginx?

Mostly around error and cost management:

- there will be an extra network hop from the LB to the in-cluster httpd
- most LBs have their *own* health checking scheme, and the LB can fail its health check independent from the ingress controller failing its health check, leading to an artificial outage

  this is also true of routing issues, permissions, cloud quotas, all that jazz
- there are potentially two different security mechanisms: the LB and the ingress controller's, and if they don't line up, that can lead to an outage
- if one has access logging turned on, it will log twice, once at the LB and once in the ingress
- one needs to be aware of the fact that there is in-cluster routing going on, else it will be non-obvious why everything is using just one LB